# How can I avoid using global variables in simple Javascript SPA?

Tags: javascript, web-development, front-end, namespace, globals

To learn Javascript I am building a simple Single-Page Application. It is a basic slideshow app that needs only to process some basic settings and execute some behaviors. The basic structure of my code is thus:

```
var settings = { ... };

function initStartPage() { ... };
function initSlideshow() { ... };
function settingsHandler() { ... };
function doSomething() { ... };
```

... where each function needs to access and possibly modify the data contained in the variable `settings`.

I'm a little stumped on how I might be able to structure this without using global variables or unnecessarily complicated constructs. I am used to programming in Java or C, where variables for small apps can live comfortably in the main function. The only solution I can think of to get rid of the global scope is simple namespacing:

```
var namespace = {};
namespace.settings = { ... };

namespace.initStartPage = function() { ... };
namespace.initSlideshow = function() { ... };
namespace.settingsHandler = function() { ... };
namespace.doSomething = function() { ... };
```

So my questions are:

**1.** Is this a reasonable solution for a system where many parts will be accessing the same data?

**2.** Is there a better, more standard solution?

Comment: All the functions are getting `settings` directly from the scope that defines them, it just happens to be the global scope? You can pretend there is a `void main() {` ... `}` around your code if you like

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I believe that is the standard approach if you want to have PUBLIC (namespace) variables. But to make private namespace variables, the usual approach is to use a closure ([example using closure for private data](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-private))

Or, since you are learning, please consider using [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html), which directly supports private data members.

Answer (score 3):

As @Lewis Pringle said, a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) is the typical way to minimize polluting the global namespace. This comes in terms of a so called [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) - immedately invoked function expression.

With these builing blocks:

- a closure to preserve a private space
- a function, which is immediately invoked

you come to the [revealing](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) [module](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) pattern in Javascript.

```
const app = (()=>{
  const init = ()=>{
    alert("hi");
  };
  return { init: init};
})()

app.init();
```

The point is, that you have an anonymous function defined and invoked immediately after parsing where `app` holds a reference to. Everything within this anonymous function is basically private to this function. The only interfaces to the public are done via the object which is returned. Here the `init` key refers to the "private" `init` function defined in the scope of the anonymous function.

`app` holds a reference to an object, which in turn has access to this scope.

From there you could build up something like dependency injection.
The immediate invoked function could take parameters, which could be passed to the scope of the closure:

```
const c => ((a,b)=>{ ... })(a,b)
```

"injecting" prior declared `a` and `b` into `c`.